# Using session state in web-services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, session, invalidoperationexception

I have a web-service written in C# that I am consuming. I now need to make use of session state in order so that I can maintain state in between web-service calls. I've read online that I need to use internal state collections for that. I declared a class `MyDemo` that has session state turned on on its method `HelloWorld()`. However, an exception `System.InvalidOperationException` *(HttpContext is not available.   This class can only be used in the context of an ASP.NET request.)* is thrown when I try to call method `HelloWorld()`. Am I using internal state collections correctly? How should I fix my program?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace GettingStartedLib
{

    public class MyDemo : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            // get the Count out of Session State
            int Count;

            if (Session["Count"] == null)
                Count = 0;
            else
                Count = (int)Session["Count"];

            if (Count == null)
                Count = 0;

            // increment and store the count
            Count++;
            Session["Count"] = Count;

            return "Hello World - Call Number: " + Count.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class CalculatorService : ICalculator
    {
        private int x = 0;

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
        public double Add(double n1, double n2)
        {

            MyDemo demo = new MyDemo();
            string sample = demo.HelloWorld();


            x++;
            Console.WriteLine("x = {0}", x);

            double result = n1 + n2;
            Console.WriteLine("Received Add({0},{1})", n1, n2);
            // Code added to write output to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine("Return: {0}", result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's because the context cannot be passed to the HelloWorld. Additionally, does ICalculator inherit from System.Web.Services.WebService? If it doesn't that may also be part of the problem.

Comment: No, it does not, but I am able to make web-service calls on CalculatorService. Here is the code for ICalculator interface:

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface ICalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        double Add(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply(double n1, double n2);
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide(double n1, double n2);
    }

And what should I do about passing the context to HelloWorld?